# How to use get all NSLocalization using genstrings while preserved current translations

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, nslocalizedstring

Let say my iOS app already have translation localizatible.strings for Japanese.  Say "Continue" = "続ける";

However, I've added new NSLocalization additions to my code but I want to use genstrings to get all new NSLocalizations without having to merge them manually.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tools that manage localization and that automatically make updates to translations based on changes to the base language (and helping the translator make the necessary changes only to whatever has been changed).

For example www.gengo.com has a free online tool called [Strings](http://ads.gengo.com/string-landing-page/) (which I haven't tried yet). There are also desktop apps that look very good, such as Localization Manager as part of Localization Suite http://www.loc-suite.org/ (which I haven't tried properly yet either).

Localization agencies may have their own tools, too.

These tools are a must if you do a lot of updates and have several languages but for smaller projects, they can take a bit too much getting used to. For an occasional task or a small project with few languages, manually merging the changes of your base language localizable.strings files to your translated localizable.strings files might be quicker though.