# how to extract NSStrings from objective-c code

Tags: objective-c, localization, internationalization, nsstring, nslocalizedstring

I want to extract all the Strings from my codebase and put in an excel sheet. What is the best way to do that? And how can I do that?

To add on it. I am able to search all the strings in my project using the following expression:

```
@"(any)"
```

where (any) is the pattern available in Xcode search. I am able to search all the strings. I want to extract all those and put it in a list/excel sheet. How should I do that?

===EDIT===

2nd Part of my question. I have a string @"abc", How can I replace it to NSLocalizedString(@"abc", @"abc", nil) using Find/Replace in Xcode?

Comment: are you going to want to re-import those strings into your project (i.e. translation or localization)?

Comment: actually yes, I have to give all these strings to client so that he can translate these strings and 2nd part is I have convert all these strings to NSLocalizedString(@"xxx", @"xxx"). If there is a way I can convert @"abc" to NSLocalizedString(@"abc", @"abc", nil), then i can use genstrings to extract the strings, so I need either solution.

Comment: i googled it and saw people using \1 \2 for the placeholders. but it is now working in my case, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: it is "now" working?  or ***not*** working?  Also, [see this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395449/how-to-use-get-all-nslocalization-using-genstrings-while-preserved-current-trans?rq=1).

Comment: I figured it out. I had selected wrong Find option, I was searching text, I changed it to Regular Expression and @"(.*)" expression worked. and I replaced it with NSLocalizedString(@"\1", @"\1", nil)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had selected wrong Find option, I was searching text, I changed it to Regular Expression and `@"(.*)"` expression worked. and I replaced it with `NSLocalizedString(@"\1", @"\1", nil)`